# Laptop speaker only makes tinny noise with Windows 10 default sounds

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, speakers

When I play any default Windows 10 sounds (like the UAC, volume control or Error sound effects), one of my speakers sounds a bit tinny. Any other audio and it sounds perfect. I've opened up the laptop and cleaned the speakers with 91% Isopropyl alcohol to no avail. I've also tried reinstalling the drivers but that didn't work. What exactly could be the issue?

Comment: One cause: slightly loose mount and excessive mechanical vibration.

Comment: I was thinking about the same... but if this affects _only_ Windows sounds while any other audio sounds perfect...

Comment: @John the speakers don't have any screws for mounting, they're fixed in place

Comment: Windows sounds tend to be one frequency or a narrow range causing resonance.

Comment: Windows might be using different default output device for system sounds and the volume there is set to min. Navigate to audio settings, choose the output device > go to 'Properties' button and tweak it's volume in a 'Levels' tab.

Comment: @John This never used to happen to my speaker before. The chimes used to sound crisp. I opened my laptop a while ago for cleaning and this happened after I closed it. But I didn't touch the speakers.

Comment: After further testing, this only seems to be the problem with the left speaker.

Comment: I don't think this is a software issue (at least very uncommon if so) . No issues here on any laptop.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Have the laptop serviced perhaps